# ManyToMany. How to properly create `Follow` object?

Tags: django

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    follow = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='following')
```

**views:**

```
user_to_follow = User.objects.get(id=follow_id)
f = Follow.objects.create(follow = user_to_follow)
```

How to properly create `Follow` object in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For [ManyToMany fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships), You would do:

```
user_to_follow = User.objects.get(id=follow_id)
f = Follow.objects.create(user=request.user) #or user=whatever
f.follow.add(user_to_follow)
```

Or

```
user_to_follow = User.objects.get(id=follow_id)
f = Follow(user=request.user) #or user=whatever
f.save()
f.follow.add(user_to_follow)
```

I would also do

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
user_to_follow = get_object_or_404(User, id=follow_id)
```

because, `User.objects.get(id=follow_id)` would throw a `500` if a `user` with `follow_id` is not present in the database.